# FOundation emails --- thunderbird rwd

Tags: html, inky

I have created responsive email message and it works but the problem is on Thunderbird.When i go under the breakpoint all my columns looks like 100% of width but should be 50%.
I add some screens view and my code.
Please help ...

screen 1 - correct 
http://elskiba.pl/mobile-view.jpg
screen -1 Thunderbird 
http://elskiba.pl/html-mail-issue.jpg

```html
<container
 style="border-bottom:1px solid #ffcc00;padding:0 2px;background:#fff;"
>
 <row class="collapse">
  <columns small="12" large="6">
   <row>
    <!-- column 1 -->
    <columns
     small="4"
     style="padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:5px;padding-right:0"
    >
     <img
      width="106"
      src="{{ faceurl }}"
      alt="portret"
      style="width:106px;max-width:106px"
      class="float-center"
     />
    </columns>
    <!-- column 1-- end -->
    <!-- column 2 -->
    <columns
     small="8"
     style="padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:20px"
    >
     <row>
      <columns small="2" large="2" align="center">
       <a
        href="{{ linkedinlink }}"
        style="margin-right:8px;display:block"
        ><img
         width="25"
         height="25"
         src="https://chop-chop.org/app/uploads/2019/02/linkedin_yellow_icon.jpg"
         alt="linkedin"
         class="float-right"
       /></a>
      </columns>
      <columns small="10" large="10">
       <h1 style="line-height: 1">
        <a href="{{ linkedinlink }}"
         ><strong>{{ name }}</strong></a
        >
       </h1>
       <p style="line-height: 1">{{ position }}</p>
      </columns>
     </row>

     <spacer size="18"></spacer>

     <row>
      <columns small="2" large="2"></columns>
      <columns small="10" large="10">
       <p style="color:#000">
        <strong
         ><a
          href="{{ contact }}"
          style="text-decoration:none;"
          ><span
           style="color:#000 !important;text-decoration:none !important"
           >{{ contact }}</span
          ></a
         ></strong
        >
       </p>
       <p style="color:#000">
        <a href="http://chop-chop.org"
         ><strong
          ><span
           style="color:#000;text-decoration:none"
           >chop-chop.org</span
          ></strong
         ></a
        >
       </p>
       <p style="color:#000">
        <a href="http://chop-chop.org/blog"
         ><span
          style="color:#000;text-decoration:none"
          >chop-chop.org/blog</span
         ></a
        >
       </p>
      </columns>
     </row>
    </columns>
    <!-- column 2-- end -->
   </row>
  </columns>
  <columns small="12" large="6">
   <row>
    <columns
     small="4"
     large="4"
     style="padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:20px"
    >
     <a href="http://chop-chop.org" style="display:block">
      <img
       width="61"
       height="71"
       src="{{ companylogo }}"
       alt="company logo"
       class="float-center"
      />
     </a>
    </columns>
    <!-- column 4 -->
    <columns
     small="8"
     large="8"
     style="padding-top:14px; padding-bottom:20px"
    >
     <row>
      <columns small="2" large="0"></columns>
      <columns small="10" large="12">
       <h2><strong>Chop-Chop Sp.z.o.o.</strong></h2>
       <p>
        <span style="color:#000;text-decoration:none"
         >ul Szewska 3a</span
        >
       </p>
       <p style="color:#000">
        <span style="color:#000;text-decoration:none"
         >50-053 Wrocław PL
        </span>
       </p>
      </columns>
     </row>
     <spacer size="18"></spacer>
     <row>
      <columns small="2" large="0" valign="bottom"></columns>
      <columns small="10" large="12" valign="bottom">
       <a
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/chop-chop-org"
        ><img
         width="25"
         height="25"
         src="https://chop-chop.org/app/uploads/2019/02/linkedin_icon.jpg"
         alt="linkedin"
         style="display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:25px;height:25px"
       /></a>

       <a href="https://www.instagram.com/chopchopers/"
        ><img
         width="25"
         height="25"
         src="https://chop-chop.org/app/uploads/2019/02/instagram_icon.jpg"
         alt="instagram"
         style="display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:25px;height:25px"
       /></a>

       <a href="https://www.facebook.com/chopchoporg"
        ><img
         width="25"
         height="25"
         src="https://chop-chop.org/app/uploads/2019/02/facebook_icon.jpg"
         alt="facebook"
         style="display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:25px;height:25px"
       /></a>

       <a href="https://github.com/chop-chop-org"
        ><img
         width="25"
         height="25"
         src="https://chop-chop.org/app/uploads/2019/02/github_icon.jpg"
         alt="github"
         style="display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:25px;height:25px"
       /></a>

       <a href="https://clutch.co/profile/chop-chop"
        ><img
         width="25"
         height="25"
         src="https://chop-chop.org/app/uploads/2019/02/clutch_icon.jpg"
         alt="clutch"
         style="display:inline-block;margin-right:4px;width:25px;height:25px"
       /></a>
      </columns>
     </row>
    </columns>
    <!-- column 4 end -->
   </row>
  </columns>
 </row>
</container>
```

Comment: 1. Can you test it in a webmail on firefox ?. 2. Did you minify the code generated by inky ? I think Inky uses `display: inline-block` to make the grid, and this can cause troubles on firefox because it renders one extra space, which causes your div to be 51% instead of 50%. By minifying the code you get rid of this space.

Comment: Yes , i minifyed the code . I have tested it on Email On Acid and I was satisfied.

Comment: And the funny thing is when i have massage preview  it looks ok.http://elskiba.pl/html-th.jpg